# To store Datetime type in csv file

Tags: python, csv, dataframe

I want to store Datetime in CSV file.
I tried following code

```
date=location.iloc[0,1]
lastdate=location.iloc[len(location)-1,1]
import csv
f = open('numbers3.csv', 'w')

with f:

    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(fields)
    while(date==lastdate) or (date<lastdate):
        print(date)
        strr=str(date)
        writer.writerow(str(date))
        date=date+timedelta(minutes=15)
```

output for this is [image]

And I want the following output
[image]

Comment: Please remove screenshots and add text instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a list of `datetime` to a column in a `csv` file, you need to put all `datetime` elements in a list with this format:

```
datetimes = [['2020-10-10 13:12'], ['2020-10-10 13:12'], ['2020-10-10 13:12'], ['2020-10-10 13:12']]
myFile = open('/path/csvexample3.csv', 'w')
with myFile:
    writer = csv.writer(myFile)
    writer.writerows(datetimes)
```

Then you are good to go. Note that each date is in a `list`, and the `datetimes` is a `list` of `list`